# Facebook Description not Working at Recommend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have this problem:
A page, properly configured for facebook:

```
    <html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"  
        xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

(I also tried with:)

```
    <html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"  
        xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/facebook#">
```

(And some others)

In the head, the corresponding OG codes: app_id, url, type, title, image, description, site_name.

Then, in the page, the like button:

```
    <fb:like href="##my_url##" send="false" layout="button_count" show-faces="false" action="recommend"></fb:like>
```

But, when the button it's pressed and the form it's sent, in Facebook, it appear something like:

```
    No hay ninguna descripción disponible para esta frase
    No hay ninguna descripción disponible para esta frase
    No hay ninguna descripción disponible para esta frase
    No hay ninguna descripción disponible para esta frase
```

In the description... (spanish account).
The title and the image, don't have problems at all.
I had tested the URL with the [Debug Page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), but I don't get any errors, and it reads the description properly.

**Update:**  I've made a test Page with only the essential, but I got the same result: 
http://www.cooperativa.cl/noticias/mundo/test-facebook/2012-12-11/160015.html

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) say for the URL? are your meta tags being picked up correctly?

Comment: Yeah, all field are picked properly. This is an example of the [Debug to my Page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cooperativa.cl%2Fnoticias%2Fmundo%2Fcolombia%2Fnicaragua-autorizo-que-ee-uu-patrulle-en-zona-zanjada-por-la-haya%2F2012-11-29%2F225510.html)

Comment: did you also try the html5 version of the like button? especially to test if the code is the problem.

Comment: I've just tried, but I got the same result

Comment: This is loading fine for me per your Metadata?

http://i.stack.imgur.com/SPaR9.png

Comment: That's weird... maybe a configuration of my facebook's account it's messed up? You used the like button of my page or another testing?

Answer (score 0):

Add the meta tag in the html head with the descritption

```
 <meta property="og:description"  content="Bla bla bla " />
```

Comment: sorry i try whit this again and it dont works now :( this happend with facebook like buttom in spanish only? or you  get a "no description for this phrase" message if you use it in english ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Argentina, and I've found this happens if I use Facebook in Spanish language [es_LA], but if I use it in Spanish (Spain) [es_ES] the post shows correctly.

The weird thing is that on my website (I have this problem too on my website) I'm using the JS SDK in es_LA and not in es_ES.

Obviously, if you use Facebook un English the post will show correctly.